# new View.OnClickListener() Button Crashes the whole application

Tags: java, android-studio, crash

everything was fine with my application, this morning when I try to run it and press on the "Register" button the application crashes.
Same goes for another button in the code.
Inside the IDE (Android Studio) where it says

```
btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

Not sure what I added or charged but here is my code.
Not sure if I should add all the code because its too long.

**XML FILE**

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.505"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cbAgreement" />
```

and here is my Java code

```
btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);


        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                initRegister();
            }
        });

private void initRegister(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initRegister: Started");
        if (validateData())
        {
            if (cbAgreement.isChecked())
            {
                showSnackBar();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "You need to agree to the License Agreement", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

private void showSnackBar(){
        Log.d(TAG, "showSnackBar: Started");

        txtFullName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txtPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        edtTxtRePassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        String name = edtTxtFullName.getText().toString();
        String email = edtTxtEmail.getText().toString();
        String country = countrySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String gender = "";

        switch (radioGroupGender.getCheckedRadioButtonId())
        {
            case R.id.rbMale:
                gender = "Male";
                break;
            case R.id.rbFemale:
                gender = "Female";
                break;
            case R.id.rbOther:
                gender = "Other";
                break;
            default:
                gender = "Unknown";
                break;
        }

        String snackText =
                "Name " + name + "\n" +
                "Email " + email + "\n" +
                "Gender " + gender + "\n" +
                "Country " + country + "\n";

        Snackbar.make(parent, name + " Registered!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("Dismissed", view -> {
                    txtFullName.setText("");
                    txtEmail.setText("");
                    txtPassword.setText("");
                    txtRePassword.setText("");
                }).show();

    }
```

Logcat

```
2021-06-17 18:27:06.107 10598-10598/com.example.registerform D/MainActivity: validateData: Started
2021-06-17 18:27:06.107 10598-10598/com.example.registerform E/le.registerfor: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2021-06-17 18:27:06.107 10598-10598/com.example.registerform D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-06-17 18:27:06.113 10598-10598/com.example.registerform E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.registerform, PID: 10598
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:381)
        at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getText(MiuiResources.java:97)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6397)
        at com.example.registerform.MainActivity.validateData(MainActivity.java:118)
        at com.example.registerform.MainActivity.initRegister(MainActivity.java:57)
        at com.example.registerform.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:19)
        at com.example.registerform.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7183)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7156)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:820)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27650)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7561)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
2021-06-17 18:27:06.128 10598-10598/com.example.registerform D/OOMEventManagerFK: checkEventAndDumpForJE: 0
2021-06-17 18:27:06.164 10598-10598/com.example.registerform I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10598 SIG: 9
```

```
    private boolean validateData(){
        Log.d(TAG, "validateData: Started");

        if(edtTxtFullName.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            txtFullName.setText(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
        if(edtTxtEmail.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            txtEmail.setText(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
        if(edtTxtPassword.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            txtPassword.setText(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
        if(edtTxtRePassword.getText().toString().equals(""))
        {
            txtRePassword.setText(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
        if(!edtTxtPassword.getText().toString().equals(edtTxtRePassword.getText().toString())){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password Doesn't Match.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            txtRePassword.setText(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

```
    private void initViews(){
        Log.d(TAG,"Started");

        edtTxtFullName = findViewById(R.id.edtTxtFullName);
        edtTxtEmail = findViewById(R.id.edtTxtEmail);
        edtTxtPassword = findViewById(R.id.edtTxtPassword);
        edtTxtRePassword = findViewById(R.id.edtTxtRePassword);

        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnImage =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnImage);

        txtFullName = findViewById(R.id.txtFullName);
        txtEmail = findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        txtPassword = findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
        txtRePassword = findViewById(R.id.txtRePassword);

        countrySpinner = findViewById(R.id.countrySpinner);
        radioGroupGender = findViewById(R.id.radioGroupGender);
        cbAgreement = findViewById(R.id.cbAgreement);
        parent = findViewById(R.id.parent);


    }
```

Comment: The greyed out area should be that you can convert to a lambda -- it should say if you hover over it and fix automatically if you press alt + enter. The error should be from somewhere else, not the greyed out portion.

Comment: What is in the lambada is the same, either way it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, so I said -- the error is somewhere else, not in the greyed portion.

Comment: Any idea what could cause this button to crash the whole app? :/

Comment: Does the other button cause the app to crash or is it just another example of the greyed out code?

Comment: No, it doesn't after casting it.
what I mean is I just added (Button) and it stopped crashing, but this one is still.

Comment: Okay, I think I found it. In your `initRegister()` function, what is your `cbAgreement` variable? I don't see your declaration anywhere. Also, you can check the Logcat to see what the error was to make debugging easier.

Comment: Also, in `showSnackBar()`, you use a lot of undefined variables as well. Not sure if those are problems since you didn't include the entire class code but it's a potential source.

Comment: Hey, I have edited my post, can you please check it out.
About the 'showSnackBar()' I was using them before, but I have changed them for now.
'cbAgreement' is a checkbox.

Comment: The error is in your `validateData()` function, according to the Logcat. Please provide the code for that function as well, thanks :)

Comment: I have added it as well!

Comment: Ok, your problem is you used `setText()` with `View.VISIBLE`. Make sure you set an actual string/string resource or use `setVisibility()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app is crashing because of this (in the `validateData()`) function:

```
txtFullName.setText(View.VISIBLE);
```

and the other lines that look like that. `TextView`'s `setText()` function should be used with `String`, `CharSequence`, etc., so this is the wrong function for setting visibility, which is what I'm assuming you are trying to do.

Instead, use this:

```
txtFullName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

which should make the `View` visible.

In the future, using the stack trace the Logcat prints out and debugging tools that Android Studio provides will make tracking and fixing errors much easier.